# How to create google app script 14 day reminder email to self based on date in cell

Tags: javascript

Please can you help me with this? I would like to send my self an email every 14 days from a date in a google sheet with the email containing some further information from a cell or two. I have the below code but I do not know how to use datediff in google app script as I copied datediff from excel vba. I also think my code structure is wrong and emails will be sent all the time in the codes current form.

```
function sendEmails() {

var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();  // Today's date, without 
time
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 999;   // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells A2:B999
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 999)
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var reminderDate = row[0].toLocaleDateString();  // Sale start date
var propertyAddress = row[1];  // The address of the property
var subject = row[1]; // Email subject
var myemail = 'test@test.com';
}


   function setTrigger(){

  var reminderDate = row[0].toLocaleDateString();  // Sale start date
  //This trigger will set 14 days reminder trigger set in 
 createFourteenDaysTrigger function.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createFourteenDaysReminderTrigger')
      .timeBased()
      .atDate(reminderDate) //format -> .atDate(2017, 04, 01) 
      .atHour(12)
      .create();
 }

 function createFourteenDaysReminderTrigger() {
   //This trigger will send emails after 14 days
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendReminderEmail')
     .timeBased()
     .everyDays(14)
     .create()
}

function sendReminderEmail(){

  MailApp.sendEmail(myemail, subject, propertyAddress);// Sending of 
the email
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Time based trigger in App script to send reminder email after every 14 days, for this you need to create the 2 triggers, first one is for start trigger on your reminder date and second one is for create reminder for every 14 days,

try with a following sample code.

```
     function setTrigger(){

      //Your other code goes here

      var reminderDate = row[0].toLocaleDateString();  // Sale start date
      //This trigger will set 14 days reminder trigger set in createFourteenDaysTrigger function.
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('createFourteenDaysReminderTrigger')
          .timeBased()
          .atDate(reminderDate) //format -> .atDate(2017, 04, 01) 
          .atHour(12)
          .create();
     }

     function createFourteenDaysReminderTrigger() {
       //This trigger will send emails after 14 days
       ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendReminderEmail')
         .timeBased()
         .everyDays(14)
         .create()
    }

    function sendReminderEmail(){

      MailApp.sendEmail(myemail@me.com, 14 Day Sales Chase Due, propertyAddress);// Sending of the email

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Nitin, I have tried the above, but no email is sent. Any ideas where I have gone wrong please? I have updated the full code in my original post.

Comment: An email will be send after 14 days after reminder date as per code, try with running simple test function to verify email is working or not.

Comment: Is myemail@me.com valid email address? and you have updated your code where you have defined function inside function, please verify the code.

Comment: Hi Nitin, I am testing with a valid email and have corrected the defined function inside another function. The debugger is saying : TypeError: Cannot find function toLocaleDateString in object . (line 15, file "Code". I have updated my post again to current. Any ideas please?